# android java convert byte array to file

Tags: java, android

could i convert `byte array` to an `file` without save it i just want to upload the `byte array (image)` to my php server but before that's i must convert it to an file for be able to upload it

here i get that byte array from intent

```
 byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
```

and i convert it to bitmap for display it to user

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

but i cant convert it to file for upload that's image
any idea ?

Comment: The process of "converting a image to a file" is called saving. You should search on google "How can i save a bitmap" and you will find plenty of results

Answer (score 0):

A `File` object only represents information about a file, not the file content itself. Hence, you cannot "convert" a byte array to a `File` object.

Most probably, you will have to save it to a file prior to the upload, but that is difficult to answer without knowing how you upload the file.

Comment: i use Volley Multipart Request for upload the images simple example 
`this.builder.addFormDataPart(name, fileName, RequestBody.create(
  MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), new File(filePath)));`

Comment: I did a quick google search and couldn't find any possibility to pass a byte array to volley. I guess you will have to save it to a file first.